# Installing Java 1.5 on Debian

Tags: java, linux, debian

I'm trying to install Java 1.5 on Debian.

But when I write

```
apt-get install java-package
```

in `bash`, the error

> unable to locate package java-package

is shown. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try running `apt-get update` and see if it works now

Comment: On Ubuntu, the package is named "openjdk-6-jre" for the OpenJDK JVM.

Comment: Don't you use `sudo ...` for apt-get?

Answer (score 7):

That's probably because there is no `java-package` in Debian (where did you get that package name, BTW?)…

What you need is one of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) packages:

- [sun-java6-jre](http://packages.debian.org/sid/sun-java6-jre) is [the standard JRE from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (previously SUN)
- [openjdk-6-jre](http://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-6-jre) is from [the free software version of the previous](http://openjdk.java.net/)
- [gcj-jre](http://packages.debian.org/sid/gcj-jre) is the JRE that can both run JVM's bytecode and load native code classes as compiled with [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)

This is to be able to run Java applications. If you want to develop, just install the corresponding `-jdk` package (e.g. `sun-java6-jdk`).

Answer (score 1):

To intall Java Runtime Environment on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

```
# apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

To intall package to developing programs using Java on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

```
# apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

from http://namhuy.net/1195/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-7.html